# .NET 6 Logging to Elasticsearch using Serilog

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-6.0, serilog

I develop a worker application using .NET 6 and I use Serilog for logging to Elasticsearch; I'm trying to configure Serilog but the index doesn't create on elastic and I don't get any error to solve it.

My program.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                
                .UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
                    {
                        configuration.Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                            .WriteTo.Console()
                            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                                new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"))
                                {
                                    IndexFormat =
                                        $"Elastic-logs-ApprovalCycle-{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName?.ToLower().Replace(".", "-")}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd}",
                                    TypeName = null,
                                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                                    BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
                                    CustomFormatter = new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter(),
                                    OverwriteTemplate = true,
                                    DetectElasticsearchVersion = true,
                                    AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
                                    NumberOfReplicas = 1,
                                    NumberOfShards = 2,
                                    FailureCallback = e => Console.WriteLine("Unable to submit event " + e.MessageTemplate),
                                    EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                                                       EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                                                       EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback |
                                                       EmitEventFailureHandling.ThrowException
                                })
                            .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
                           
                    }
                    
                )
                
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    Log.Information("test log");
                    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
                    services.AddSerilog();
                    services.AddSingleton(rabbit);
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
                });
    }
```

Worker.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Approval.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SSRM;
using ILogger = Serilog.ILogger;

namespace Approval
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RmqOptions _options;
        private readonly RmqListener<> _listener;
        public Worker(ILogger logger,RmqOptions options)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _options = options;
            _listener=new RmqListener<>(options);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Information("Start listen ... ");
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await _listener.Listen("Queue");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Information("Listen to Queue: 'Queue' Exception" + e);
            }
        }
        



        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await ApprovalDriver.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

packages

```
      <PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.17.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="6.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="restsharp" Version="110.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="serilog.aspnetcore" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" Version="9.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" Version="9.0.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Synergy.Contracts" Version="2.0.132" />
      <PackageReference Include="WorkflowCore.Persistence.MySQL" Version="3.0.1" />
```

I notice that the log command in program.cs doesn't log to console.

console output

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.2.1\plugins\dpa\DotFiles\JetBrains.DPA.Runner.exe" --handle=5600 --backend-pid=28808 --detach-event-name=dpa.detach.5600 C:/Users/u12749/Desktop/update/Approval/Approval/bin/Debug/net6.0/Approval.exe
[10:22:50 INF] Start listen ... 
Unable to submit event Start listen ...
Unable to submit event Start listen ...
```

appsettongs.json

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're targeting `http://localhost:9200`. Does Elastic run on your local machine at port 9200? Does it run inside a container whose port isn't exposed perhaps?

Comment: yes, I run elasticsearch on my local machine.

Comment: The error says the endpoint isn't accepting events. How did you test that the service is running and port 9200 is listening? How are you running Elastic?

Comment: I run elasticsearch on windows and when I open this url : "https://localhost:9200/"
I got that elastic is running

Comment: I noticed that when I open "https://localhost:9200" I got the site is not secure but it open, but when I try to open "localhost:9200" it is not open.

Comment: Have you tried with *fewer* options? Also bear in mind that Elastic provides its own sink now, [Elastic.Serilog.Sinks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elastic.Serilog.Sinks#readme-body-tab). The author of your current package suggests trying Elastic's sink first. No matter the sink, try using it with the minimum configuration first.

Comment: `I got the site is not secure` that's because `http://` was used. This could be the issue. Almost everything uses HTTPS by default these days. Inside a Kubernetes cluster there's no need because only configured services can talk to each other. In an out of the box installation, HTTPS may be enabled by default.

Comment: I edit "kibana.yml" and "elasticsearch.yml" and now "http://localhost:9200" is open, and the problem has been solved.
thank you.